# how to add result from another method to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following method and i am trying to add the `customer_status.status` to the result array but getting error `undefined method <<`

```
def self.latest_customer_details(user_id)
  latest = latest_within_last_year(user_id)
  return nil unless latest.present?
  customer_status = customer_status(user_id)
  result = Customer.new('customer_info', latest.customer_info, latest.status, latest.purchase_date)
  result << customer_status.status
end
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: `result` is a `Customer` object, not an array. Your last line will only work if `Customer` inherits from Array.

Answer (score -1):

Because of this line:

```
customer_status = customer_status(user_id)
```

The variable customer_status becomes the return value or last line of customer_status(user_id). So when you try to call the customer_status.status, it doesn't know how to call that because the customer_status method has been overwritten.